# Excel VBA - A general how to

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to figure out a way to take some data in a sheet and then carry it over to another sheet and change the formatting of it. In essence, I have a set employees, skills, branches and tiers. Rather than have a long list of each skill name and a separate row for each employee, I'd like to have (see 2nd image) the employee names listed under the skill name in a table.

Here is the spreadsheet with the data:

[image]

And then I'd like to format the data like so in the second sheet using an update button:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This site is not for general how to's... but look into long to wide table format conversion.

Comment: Some Pivot Table magic might get this done. Just something to try...

Comment: @gtwebb - I couldn't think of a good way of describing this, so I thought a "general how to" would be a good place to start for the title.. but thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into it.

Comment: This question is currently too broad - please see the [help] pages on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pivot Table should do it for you!!

[image]

[image]